# Mysql Sub queries

Tags: mysql

I need help to write a subquery.

I have an article table with categories that has featured and un-featured articles.

I want to pick 4 latest featured articles of a particular category which do not fall in top 6 latest featured articles regardless of category. This is what I have done

```
select title 
from node 
where nid NOT IN(select nid from node order by date limit 6) 
order by date 
limit 4
```

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, `LIMIT` is not yet supported in an `IN()` subquery. Instead you need to `LEFT JOIN` against a subquery and look for `NULL`s in the subquery:

```
SELECT title
FROM 
  node
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT nid FROM node ORDER BY date LIMIT 6 ) nids ON node.nid = nids.nid
WHERE 
  nids.nid IS NULL
  AND node.category = 'some category'
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a bit here, but you mean something like this?

```
select title 
from node 
where nid NOT IN(select nid from node where featured = 1 order by date desc limit 6) 
and featured = 1
and category = ...
order by date desc
limit 4
```